# Added Listen 443 in remote server's sshd_config. Why I can't ssh -p 443 / 22?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

In a moment of weakness I sheepishly followed a [tutorial](http://www.verot.net/socks.htm) on how to connect to my Amazon EC2 remote server bypassing a public library's Wifi ssh restriction.

So first thing I did was adding the following (last) line to my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file residing in my remote EC2 AMazon server:

```
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress 443
```

Then I restarted the ssh server and, in a genius move, *logged out* from my remote server. So when in my local machine I do this...

```
$ ssh -i  /path/to/key.pem xxx@xx.xx.xxx.xx -p 443 -v
```

...I get this:

```
$ ssh -i /path/to/key.pem xxx@xx.xx.xxx.xx -v -p 443
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xx [xx.xx.xxx.xx] port 443.
debug1: connect to address xx.xx.xxx.xx port 443: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xxx.xx port 443: Connection timed out
```

If I try to ssh to default's port 22 I get this:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xx [xx.xx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xx.xx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

I also added the following line in my Amazon's EC2 'Security Groups'...

```
Custom TCP port 443
```

... to no avail.

Did I effectively locked me out of my remote server? I was following a tutorial on how to tunnel and then this happened. Shouldn't have just added to /etc/ssh/sshd_config...

```
Port 443
```

...instead of 'ListenAddress 443' ?

I have never had problems ssh'ing to my remote server before (which is a Debian Wheezy).

As far as I know I can still detach my volume, re-attach it into a new instance, fix the sshd_config file, etc. I hope there's an alternative to that.

So my question is: It is possible to connect to my remote server considering the line 'ListenAddress 443' in ssh_config ? If so, how? And perhaps more importantly, why is that I can't connect on Port 22 if I hadn't touched or changed anything n sshd_config besides the ListenAddress 443?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

```
telnet xx.xx.xxx.xx 22
Trying xx.xx.xxx.xx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect because of one of three reasons:

1. `sshd` on the remote server is down because it can't parse `ListenAddress 443`.
2. `sshd` parsed `ListenAddress 443` into an IP address ('443' can be interpreted as an IP address - an IPv4 address is represented at low levels by a 32-bit unsigned integer) but was unable to bind to the IP address represented by '443' and is down.
3. `sshd` parsed `ListenAddress 443` into an IP address, successfully bound to that IP address, and is now running and listening for incoming connections on "0.0.1.187" or some similar interpretation of '443' as an IP address.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! Say I'm in the 3rd case...Would it be possible for me to modify settings on my local machine to connect to whatever is the interpretation of '443' as an IP Address in the remote server? It seems to me the tutorial is misguiding when it says we should add Listen 443 in sshd_config to bypass restrictions. Perhaps he/she meant to say Port 443.

Comment: Possible?  You'd have to spoof your address (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).  You could source-route (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_routing) your packets, **and** hope no part of the network drops source-routed packets along the way.  It's almost certain some network hardware along the way will just drop your source-routed packets, however.

Comment: Thanks again, Andrew! I had to go the rather painful road of dettaching the faulty volume to a debug server, fix it there to later re-attach it again. I'm stuck there at the moment (but that's another story).

Comment: By the way, I thought about disregarding the first two scenarios (i.e. ssh daemon down because ssh server can't correctly parse file)  on the grounds that when I first edited 'sshd_config' file  I wrote on it 'Listen' instead of 'ListenAddress' and the ssh server immediately complained upon restarting. I'd like to confirm these assumptions of mine with trial and error but I'm so scared right now to edit the sshd_config (even in my local machine!).

Comment: You can run another copy of sshd using another config file - use the `-f config_file` option.  Have it listen on a different port from the "normal" sshd too, so there's no possible `bind()` conflict.  See http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd